# Odoo - Import data in qweb report

Tags: report, odoo, qweb

I created a report using the model event.event .

Any problem, my report running.

Now I would like to import external data to the other model (for example: res.partner)

`class SportReport(models.AbstractModel):  
    _name = ‘report.sport_event.report_company_sport’`

```
def _get_company(self):  
    browse_reg = self.env[‘res.partner’].search([('company', '=', True)])  
    return browse_reg
```

@api.multi  def render_html(self, data=None):  
            report_obj = self.env['report']  
            report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('sport_event.report_company_sport')  
            docargs = {  
                'doc_ids': self._ids,  
                'doc_model': report.model,  
                'docs': self,
                'get_company': self._get_company,
             }  
            return report_obj.render(‘sport_event.report_company_sport', docargs)

In view :

```
<span t-raw="get_company(o)" />
```

Error :

```
QWebException: "" _get_company() takes exactly 1 argument (2given) " while evaluating
```

Where is my error ? Thanks :)

Comment: show _get_balanced() method definition and calling code.

Comment: My bad, the error is :

QWebException: "" _get_company() takes exactly 1 argument (2given) " while evaluating

Comment: it should be `<span t-esc="_get_company(o)"/>` not t-row.

Comment: refer this `http://blog.emiprotechnologies.com/create-qweb-report-odoo/ `

Comment: <span t-raw="get_company()" /> Your code should be You don't need to parse argument when calling your function. Because odoo function default take one argument as self. If you take 'o' as argument, your function took _get_company(self,o).